# Solving recursion with characteristic equation and facing complex numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

So I have to solve this recursion $b_n = b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}$ where $b_0=1$ and $b_1=8$. The characteristic equation is $x^2-x+1$. Then I calculate roots which are unfortunately complex numbers: $x_1=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. Then $b_n = A \cdot {x_1}^n + B \cdot {x_2}^n$. So I have: 
$$\begin{cases}
1=A+B\\
8=A(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i) + B(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)\end{cases}$$
Then after few transformations I have: $\frac{15}{\sqrt{3}}=(2B-1)i$.

But if I try to solve this equation I get $4B^2-4B+76=0$ which also yields negative delta... What now or what's wrong?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $x^2-x-1$ whose roots are $\displaystyle\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Sorry, I made a mistake in recursion equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{15}{\sqrt{3}}=(2B-1)i$$

then

$$-i\frac{15}{\sqrt{3}}=2B-1.$$

From $B$, draw $A$ and the rest follows.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
1&=A+B\\
8&=A\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt3}2\right)+B\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt3}2\right)\\
&=\frac12+(B-A)\frac{i\sqrt3}2\\
i\,5\sqrt3&=A-B\\
\end{align}
$$
Solving for $A$ and $B$ is now easier.

---

**Another approach:**

The characteristic equation
$$
x^2-x+1=0
$$
Has roots $e^{\pi i/3}$ and $e^{-\pi i/3}$. Thus, the solution has the form
$$
a\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}3\right)+b\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}3\right)
$$
Since $k=0$ gives $1$, we must have $a=1$. Since $k=1$ gives $8$,
$$
\frac12+b\frac{\sqrt3}2=8\implies b=5\sqrt3
$$